# KivyMD Dynamic Tab Management with different 'iterations' of tabs

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I've used the code from KivyMD documents about 'Dynamic Tab Management' so users can add / delete tabs. However, each of these tabs that are created are obviously identical and therefore the widgets that I put in it are too. This means that if I'm trying to take the id of said widget from **e.g Tab 3**, there isn't a way to do so as it is the **same id** as the widget in **e.g Tab 1**. Here is the code:

**.py file**

```
def on_start(self):
    self.add_tab()

def get_tab_list(self):
    print(self.root.ids.addworkouts.ids.tabs.get_tab_list())

def add_tab(self):
    self.index += 1
    self.root.ids.addworkouts.ids.tabs.add_widget(Tab(text=f"Exercise {self.index}"))

def remove_tab(self):
    self.index -= 1
    self.root.ids.addworkouts.ids.tabs.remove_widget(
        self.root.ids.addworkouts.ids.tabs.get_tab_list()[0]
    )
```

**.kv file**

```
<AddWorkouts>
name: 'AddWorkouts'
tabs: tabs

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MDToolbar:
        title: ' '#app.getWorkoutName()
        type: 'top'
        left_action_items: [['keyboard-backspace', lambda x: app.goBacktoMyWorkouts()]]
        #md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.accent_color
        elevation: 10


    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 0.5, 0.9
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        MDTabs:
            id: tabs

        FloatLayout:
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos

            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'y': 0.1}
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.6


            MDTextField:
                pos_hint: {'x': 0.05, 'y': 0.8}
                size_hint: 0.6, None
                hint_text: 'Exercise Name'
                helper_text_mode: 'on_focus'
                required: 'True'
                multiline: False


<Tab>

    MDList:

        MDBoxLayout:
            adaptive_height: True
            md_bg_color: 1, 1, 1, 1

            MDFlatButton:
                text: "ADD EXERCISE"
                text_color: 16/255, 167/255, 249/255, 1
                on_release: app.add_tab()

            MDFlatButton:
                text: "REMOVE LAST EXERCISE"
                text_color: 16/255, 167/255, 249/255, 1
                on_release: app.remove_tab()
```

Tab 1, where the input in MDTextField is 'Hi':

[image]

Tab2, where the input in MDTextField has duplicated from Tab:

[image]
Is there anyway of still having the users being able to add and delete Tabs, but make it so all the widgets (like the **MDTextField** in the .kv file) have different ids so I can access the user input from them? Thank you in advance, if this question has been worded badly please just ask for any more info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ids` are only populated for widgets created in a `kv` rule. So any `Tab` created outside of the `.kv` file will not be entered into the `ids` dictionary. However, you can hack them into the `ids` by modifying your `add_tab()` method:

```
import weakref
def add_tab(self):
    self.index += 1
    new_tab = Tab(text=f"Exercise {self.index}")
    new_id = 'tab_' + str(self.index)
    self.root.ids.addworkouts.ids.tabs.add_widget(new_tab)
    self.root.ids.addworkouts.ids.tabs.ids[new_id] = weakref.ref(new_tab)
```

This adds the `new_id` to the `ids` in the `MDTabs`.

To make the `MDTextField` part of the `Tab`, just add it to the `<Tab>` rule. Perhaps like this:

```
<Tab>
    MDList:
        MDTextField:
            size_hint: 0.6, None
            hint_text: 'Exercise Name'
            helper_text_mode: 'on_focus'
            required: 'True'
            multiline: False

        MDBoxLayout:
            adaptive_height: True
            md_bg_color: 1, 1, 1, 1

            MDFlatButton:
                text: "ADD EXERCISE"
                text_color: 16/255, 167/255, 249/255, 1
                on_release: app.add_tab()

            MDFlatButton:
                text: "REMOVE LAST EXERCISE"
                text_color: 16/255, 167/255, 249/255, 1
                on_release: app.remove_tab()
```

Of course, you would remove the `MDTextField` (and its enclosing `FloatLayout`) from the `<AddWorkouts>` rule.

Comment: This works, but the input in the MDTextField still duplicates between tabs. If I type 'Hi' into the text field in Tab 1, then add another tab, the message copies over. How do I change it so each new tab iteration 'refreshes' the widgets?

Comment: The `MDTextField` is not in a `Tab`, it is in the `FloatLayout` within the `AddWorkouts` `Screen`. So changing tabs has no effect on it. It is not being duplicated, it just isn't part of the `Tab`.

Comment: Ah okay that makes a lot more sense. So what I want is seperate FloatLayouts for each tab so that the MDTextField will differ? How would I do this?

Comment: thanks @JohnAnderson , i close to solve the same problem but it get this error " AttributeError: 'MainApp' object has no attribute 'index'